# How to get user information after successful authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Get the user information after successful authentication.

### The problem

Take a look in the following fragment of code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Authenticate(User userModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (userModel.IsValid(userModel.Email, userModel.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication
                .SetAuthCookie(userModel.Email, userModel.Remember);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manager");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

As you can see, it is a normal authentication's controller. What I need is simple: if the statement `userModel.IsValid` is true, how can I get the user information based on the email that he sent to the server by `userModel.Email`?

Maybe store the email on the session and in the `Index` method call some method to get the (user) information passing through parameter the email that inhabiting the session? (I think this isn't the best way because if the cookie exist and the session not, there will be a problem here.)

### Code spotlight

To get information of some user, I'm using a simple method: `User.Invoke((string) userEmail)`.

### Knowledge improvement

I'm logging in on my website with `email` and `password` as various applications of the world do. With the `email` that the user enters, I'm attempting to get his information from database. So I ask: is this the best way to do this? Maybe isn't better firstly get the ID of the user by his email and then select his information?

### What I already tried

In the `Authenticate` method (the same that I passed before), I implemented the following code:

```
[...]
public ActionResult Authenticate(User userModel)
    [...]
    if (userModel.IsValid(userModel, userModel.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication
            .SetAuthCookie(userModel.Email, userModel.Remember);

        Session["UserEmail"] = userModel.Email; // <-- Pay attention to this

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manager");
    }
    [...]
}
```

And then, in the `Index` method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(Request.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        UserProfile user = User.Invoke(Session["UserEmail"]));
        return View(user);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But as I said, if the cookie that flags that the user is logged in is alive and the session not, there will be a problem right here — a kind of *concept conflict* (cookie vs. session).

What can I do?

Comment: I really don't understand why you just can't get the email with this.User in a controller (or HttpContext.Current.User which leads to the same object).

Comment: I really don't understand what you can't understand, haha. As I said, `IsAuthenticated()` depends of a cookie... And what if the cookie exist but the session with user's email not?

Comment: Why would you need the session and not rely only on the cookie? In your example you have two different actions, if the Authenticate sets the cookie then Index can surely access the user object whic is set by the Forms Authentication module automatically during each single request. Also, you ask for help but sound ironic. That won't help.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'm starting to "get" what you're saying. Is something like this: in the `Index` method use `User.Invoke(User.Identity.Name)`, right?

Comment: Exactly, the this.User.Identity.Name is a most straightforward way of retrieving the identity set by the forms module.

Comment: Oh, how stupid I was... Your explanation was perfect for my case — thanks! Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer (from the discussion with the OP) is : the most straightforward way of retrieving the user name set by the forms authentication module is to use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

or just

```
this.User.Identity.Name
```

in a controller.